# Unknown CMake command 'swig_add_module'

Tags: python, c++, cmake, swig

I'm trying to run code with armanpy but it fails to compile with the error `Unknown CMake command 'swig_add_module'`, the log file doesn't specify any errors only the cmd does.

I've tried installing swig, changing the `CMakeLists.txt` file all without help.

This is the code:

https://sourceforge.net/p/armanpy/code/ci/master/tree/

The error happens here:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/your/armadillo/include
```

(steps from the wiki, I have changed the paths to fit my environment) I tried various variations of this step as well.

Comment: Please, provide **exact error message**. Such message should include also a call-stack of CMake functions. (It looks like you call `cmake` with `examples/` subdirectory being as a source one (the one referred by `..` relative path). This is wrong: `CMakeLists.txt` file in that directory is not intended to be the top-level one. You need to call `cmake` with top-level project's directory being a source directory)

Answer (score 5):

The `swig_add_module` command has been [deprecated](https://github.com/pism/pism/issues/387) since CMake 3.8. Try using the [`swig_add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseSWIG.html#command:swig_add_library) command instead.